# Is there anyway to access a trait of all element types in a scene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In one of my projects i am trying to make text size universal so it will change depending on screen size. What I am wondering is if there is a way to pull every SKLabelnode from a scene and fit it in a table aside from how i am doing it, by entering every label node into a table like this.This way i could just copy paste the function to other scenes and not have to worry about adding things to it when i produce another SKLabelnode in the scene

```
var LabelSizes = [SKLabelNode]()

 func biggerLabels(count: Int){
            LabelSizes[count].fontSize = LabelSizes[count].fontSize * 2
            gameview.labelcount += 1
            if gameview.labelcount == LabelSizes.count {gameview.labelcount = 0}
        }

        if view.bounds.width <= 414{
            print("iPhone sizes in use")
        } else {
              print("iPad sizes in use")
        LabelSizes = [infoText,settingsText,lvlselectText,playText]
            run(SKAction.repeat(SKAction.run {
                biggerLabels(count: self.gameview.labelcount)
            }, count: LabelSizes.count))
        }
```

Comment: why would you do this?  Just subclass SKLabelNode and add functionality in it.   BTW may I ask why you are using `.ResizeFill`?

Comment: Also,  never use `view.bounds` in SpriteKit ,  use `scene.frame`

Comment: enumerateChildNode and pick out all the SKLabels? Or maybe using map on the 'children' array of the scene?

Comment: "Also, never use view.bounds in SpriteKit , use scene.frame" @Knight0fDragon why not?

Comment: @Confused they are 2 different coordinate systems, even if on the off chance their unit count matches

Comment: @Confused, the best way to visually try to understand Sprite Kit scenes is to grab a piece of paper,  anything you write on the paper are your Nodes, the paper is your Scene, the desk is your view.  If I were to ask you to put a node in the center of the paper,  you would measure the paper to find it's center, not the desk, even if the paper and desk were the same size, if I asked you how you did it, you would tell me you measured the paper, not the desk.